# T-SQL syntax to filter records where the datetime variable is greater than or equal to the 1st Day of the Current Month

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime, sql-server-2014

I am using SQL Server 2014 and I need to add a line of code to my SQL query that will filter the data extracted only to those records where the `StayDate` (a column in database) is `greater than or equal to` the `1st day of the current month`.

In other words, the line of code I need is the following:

```
WHERE StayDate >= '1st Day of Current Month'
```

Note: `StayDate` is in the `datetime` format (eg: 2015-12-18 00:00:00.000)

Comment: I have tried the DATEDIFF function but I could not get it to work correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [**`EOMONTH`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/hh213020.aspx) to get the first day of current month

```
WHERE  StayDate >= Dateadd(dd, 1, Eomonth(Getdate(), -1))
```

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server 2012 and above

```
WHERE StayDate >= DATEADD(DAY, 1, EOMONTH(GETDATE(), -1))
```

Before SQL Server 2012

```
WHERE StayDate >= DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
```

Comment: Don't write duplicate answers. Initially you just had the second query

Answer (score 1):

You can try following approach:

```
declare @t datetime = '2016-02-28'
select DATEADD(D, -DATEPART(d, @t) + 1, @t)
```

So in your case:

```
WHERE StayDate >= DATEADD(D, -DATEPART(d, GETDATE()) + 1, GETDATE())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
StayDate >= DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, '19000101', GETDATE()), '19000101')
```

Answer (score 0):

One other option; since `staydate` being on or after (greater than or equal to) the first day of the current month is equivalent to searching for `staydate`s during the current month:

```
where datepart(mm, staydate) = datepart(mm, getdate())
  and datepart(yyyy, staydate) = datepart(yyyy, getdate())
```